# mysql5.7 restore all databases no database selected

Tags: mysql

I want to restore all databases in a single file, but it always showing error that I have to select a DB when running this command:

```
mysql -uroot -p < dump.sql
```

then I try to create a dummy DB and use that DB, so the command becom

```
mysql -uroot -D dummy -p < dump.sql
```

but whole tables goes to that DB. what should I do to fix it?

Comment: `dump.sql` is (or should be) a plain text file with regular SQL commands. You should be able to inspect it with any text editor.

Comment: I will, i am downloading the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into your sql file, you will see that the file doesn't contain commands such as `create database db` and `use db` etc, this is the reason that you are seeing the error because the sql file starting from creating tables and then inserting data to it. 
Either you can create db manually with the name you want then then restore the file to it or you can write sql command in the sql file to create and use db before the commands related to tables.